# Problem with installing additional drivers for AMD Trinity Radeon Mobility HD7620G

Tags: drivers, 18.04, radeon, amd-graphics

Recently I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my ASUS Notebook U38N (with an AMD  Radeon Mobility HD 7620G Graphics card).

After the initial installation and the installation of the recommended updates, there was no option shown for additional drivers for the graphics card in the Software & Updates application under the tab **Additional drivers** (only the Broadcom router for the WLAN appears here).

Previously, Linux Mint 17 was installed on this notebook. There `fglrx-updates version 2: 15.201.2-ubuntu0.14.04.1` was installed as a graphics driver - which worked so far very well.

Unfortunately, there seem to be no more recent (closed source) drivers from AMD, so I have to work with the open drivers.

The installed kernel version is 4.15.0-23-generic.

I have installed amd64-microcode via Synaptic – and it seems to work well.

```
$ dmesg | grep microcode
[1.855009] microcode: CPU0: patch_level = 0x06001119
[1.855026] microcode: CPU1: patch_level = 0x06001119
[1.855033] microcode: CPU2: patch_level = 0x06001119
[1.855047] microcode: CPU3: patch_level = 0x06001119
[1.855118] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.
```

After rebooting in nomodeset - “mode”.
I have added two repositories, [dokomix - fglrx-bionic-staging](https://launchpad.net/~dokomix/+archive/ubuntu/fglrx-bionic-staging)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dokomix/fglrx-bionic-staging
sudo apt-get update
```

and [oibaf - graphics-drivers](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
```

After adding these repositories there have been ca. 22 updates and in the **Software & Updates** application shows the option to choose between xserver-xorg and fglrx in **Additional Drivers**.

The xserver-xorg driver was checkboxed as used. (I tried to choose fglrx but it automatically switches back to xserver-xorg...)

During the reboot, both “normal” and in “nomodeset”, the boot process stopps unfortunately at the start of the User Manager.
In the “normal” mode the mouse freezes. In “nomodeset” the boot process simply stopps at starting the User Managar.

Any ideas what I could do to get the (any) graphics driver working.
Could it be a bug in the “Software & Updates” application.
Are there other repositories with stable builds of xserver-xorg-video-ati…?

Many thanks for your help.